# Prove that $f \in C^k$ if $|\hat{f}(n)|\leq C/|n|^{k+a}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm looking at some problems related to Fourier series. This one stumped me a little.

> Suppose that $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic and piecewise smooth. Show that if
>   there exist $k \in \mathbb{N}, a > 0,$ and $C > 0$ such that
>   $$|\hat{f}(n)|\leq \frac{C}{|n|^{k+a}},$$ for $n \geq N_0$, then $f
>  \in C^k$.

Note that $\hat{f}(n)$ is the Fourier coefficients of $f$. I really seem to have no idea where to start with this one. I was thinking about using the expression for the Fourier coefficients $$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \mathrm{e}^{-int}\, \mathrm{d}t$$ and bound it by $|\hat{f}(n)| \leq 1/2\pi \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|\, \mathrm{d}t$. But this throws the $n$ out of the question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated, the proposition doesn't hold. Consider the $2\pi$-periodic extension $f$ of $\chi_{[-\pi/2,\pi/2]}$. We have

$$\begin{align}
\hat{f}(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{-int}\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{-int}\,dt\\
&= \frac{i}{2\pi n}\left(e^{-in\pi/2} - e^{in\pi/2}\right)\\
&= \frac{i((-i)^n - i^n)}{2\pi n},
\end{align}$$

which is $O\left(\frac{1}{\lvert n\rvert}\right)$, but $f \notin C^0$.

If we amend the premises to $a > 1$, then an integration by parts shows

$$\begin{align}
\hat{f}(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) e^{-int}\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{i}{n}f(t)e^{-int}\right]_0^{2\pi} + \frac{1}{2\pi i n} \int_0^{2\pi} f'(t)e^{-int}\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{in} \hat{f'}(n)
\end{align}$$

for differentiable $f$ with nice enough (need not be continuous) derivative.

Now, if

$$\lvert \hat{f}(n)\rvert \leqslant \frac{C}{\lvert n\rvert^{k+a}}$$

for all large enough $n$ and some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a > 1$, then the $k$ times termwise differentiated Fourier series converges uniformly,

$$g_k(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n)(in)^k e^{int}$$

is a continuous function. Integrating $k$ times, and inserting the constant term $\hat{f}(0)$ exposes $f$ as a $k$-times continuously differentiable function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and so informative reply Daniel :) Wow $\chi$ is a really nice example of why that $a > 0$ does not work. Is the reason for having $|\hat{f}(n)|\leq C/|n|^{k+a}$ to get the coefficients in the Fourier series of $g_k(t)$ to be $|\hat{f}(n) (in)^k)| \leq C/n^a$? This is what gives the uniform convergence of the $k$'th derivative?

Comment: Right. If the coefficients are bounded by $C\cdot \lvert n\rvert^{-(1+\varepsilon)}$ for an $\varepsilon > 0$, they are summable, and the Fourier series converges absolutely and uniformly, hence the represented function is continuous. To know that the $k$-th derivative is continuous, one accommodates the $(in)^k$ one gets from differentiating $k$ times, that is, one wants the original coefficients bounded by $C\cdot \lvert n\rvert^{-(k+1+\varepsilon)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would write
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n} \hat f (n) e^{int}
$$
and notice that the given condition assures that the series of $k$-th derivatives converges uniformly. This implies that $f$ is differentiable $k$ times.